# Mirror localhost:3280/some/long/url to localhost:3000

Tags: networking, proxy, port-forwarding

I have a webservice running on localhost 3280 that exposes Elasticsearch server under `/some/long/url`. I would like to access Elasticsearch from localhost's port 3000.

Can I do this with port-forwarding, mirroring, proxy? What's the best way?

Edit: I meant the service is running on 3280 and would like to access it from 3000 that is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compared to slm's answer, having to maintain two different locations (iptables and apache) and also giving the side effect of not being able to visit / on localhost:3280, I would use just Apache to achieve the result. This will serve ElasticSearch via / on 3000 (and not "redirect" the user to localhost:3280/some/long/url - changing what url appears on browser). This solution handles both step #4 and #7 in one go (applications at #7 can redirect traffic to different IPs at level #4).

Provided you have `mod_proxy` loaded in your Apache you can change your port 3000`<VirtualHost>` (I'm assuming it's using `*` and not the 127.0.0.1 in the virtualhost declaration):

```
<VirtualHost *:3000>
    .
    .
    .

    RewriteEngine On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3280/some/long/url 
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3280/some/long/url 
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT:** Correct that the rule should be on 3000 and proxypass to 3280, clarify the differences to slm's suggestion and remove the point about changing 127.0.0.1 in the ProxyPass (as it is the virtualhost snippet is exactly what is asked in the original question).

**References:**

[Apache documentation of the Virtualhost Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost)
and
[Apache documentation of the ProxyPass Directive.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

Answer (score 2):

#### Redirecting the port

You can use the following 2 rules to do what you want:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3000 -j REDIRECT \
      --to-port 3280

$ sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.0/8 --dport 3000 -j REDIRECT \
      --to-port 3280
```

If you want to access this outside of localhost then you'll need to add this rule using the host's IP address (assuming 192.168.1.10):

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 192.168.1.10 --dport 3000 \
      -j REDIRECT --to-port 3280
```

#### Redirecting `/ -> /some/long/url`

This can be accomplished using a rewrite rule in Apache. This can be added to Apache's `httpd.conf` file, for example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /some/long/url [R=301,L]
```

#### Why 2 tools?

So why do you need `iptables` and Apache? It has to do with the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). The OSI model contains 7 layers.

> **#7.** Application (Network process to application)
>
> **#6.** Presentation (Data representation, encryption and decryption, convert       machine dependent data to machine independent data)
>
> **#5.** Session (Interhost communication, managing sessions between applications)
>
> **#4.** Transport - (End-to-end connections, reliability and flow control)
>
> **#3.** Network - (Path determination and logical addressing)
>
> **#2.** Data link - (Physical addressing)
>
> **#1.** Physical - (Media, signal and binary transmission)

`iptables` deals with #4 while Apache is dealing with the data at layer #7. Think of the data as being analogous to an envelope. The outside of the envelope contains the address of where to be delivered (this is the port #). This would be layer #4 in the OSI model.

The contents of the envelope (HTTP + the URL) needs to be manipulated by Apache at layer #7.

#### References

- [Redirecting a port to another one with iptables, including local packets](http://pierre.palatin.fr/entries/iptables-port-redirect)

Comment: Thank you for solving half of my problem. Now localhost:3000 mirrors localhost:3280. However, how can I make localhost:3000 mirror localhost:3280/some/long/url?

Comment: @dt1510 - iptables can't do URL redirections. You'll need to enlist either Apache or Nginx to to a redirect of `/` to `/some/long/url`. I didn't realize you literally wanted to redirect the URL + the port.

Comment: But I would like to mirror, rather than redirect, the user (actually a script) needs to see the url localhost:3000 although it refers to other one. Can Apache do this? Note, I want get rid of /some/long/url, rather then add it.

Comment: @dt1510 - your terminology isn't right. There is no such thing as mirroring. I know what you're asking for but the only way to do it is to redirect the traffic on port X to port Y using iptables. To act on the URLs requires a proxy and/or webserver to rewrite/redirect the URL to a different one. Not sure if you're familiar but this has to do with the OSI model: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Comment: @dt1510 - think of it like a envelope in the mail. `iptables` can only deal with the info on the outside of the envelope, whereas Apache/Nginx deal with the piece of paper that's inside the envelope.

Comment: @dt1510 there a few ways to achieve the same result, and the above solution does have some side effects (described in my answer).

Comment: @DravSloan - your solution is perfectly appropriate, the OP didn't originally state that the webservice could be moved, so my solution focused on purely redirecting. I essentially went up to the point of showing something similar in Apache w/o the inclusion of the ProxyPass nor the VirtualHost.

Comment: @slm noted :) I just wanted to clarify the reasons as to why my solution was different (so the OP and any other readers understood the differences in the approach).

Comment: @DravSloan - I've +1'd your answer. Nice and clean. If you feel like it adding links to the virtualhost & proxypass docs will likely make it even stronger 8-).